# Let $G$ be a finite simple group. Suppose that $A, B < G$, $G = AB$ and $A$ is an Abelian group. Is it true that $A \cap B=1 $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are proper subgroups of $G$, $ G = AB$ and $A$ is an Abelian group. Is it true that $A \cap B=1 $ ?

I checked it with some examples and it seems to be true; but I have no proof for it.

Comment: Have you checked it for $A_5$?

Comment: It's correct. Hint: show that $(A \cap B)^B = (A \cap B)^G$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $(A\cap B)^G$.  Is it the normalizer of $A\cap B$ in $G$?

Comment: I think $X^G := \langle X^g  \;|\; g \in G\rangle = \langle g^{-1}Xg  \;|\; g \in G \rangle $.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set $C:= A \cap B$. On the contray suppose that $C \neq 1$. So $C^B \neq 1$.
We have $C^G = C^{AB}$. Since $A$ is Abelian, $C^G = C^B$.
But $ C^G \trianglelefteq G$. Thus $C^B=C^G=G$.
For every $c \in C$ and $b \in B$, we have $c^b = b^{-1}cb \in B$, so $G = C^B \le B$, a contradiction.

Comment: It doesn't affect the validity of the proof, but $C^B=G$ means that $G$ is generated by the set $\{b^{-1}cb : c \in C, b \in B \}$, not that it is necessarily equal to that set.

Comment: I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to $A$ it is sufficient to assume that $A\cap B\unlhd A$. For example, $A$ may be Dedekind group. To answer of user180168. Thus $C^B=C^G=G$. Obviously, $G=C^B\leq B$, a contradiction.

Comment: This seems to be identical the proof already given by user180168

Comment: Now yes. Previously - not quite.

Answer (score -1):

Counter-example: Let $G= Z_p$ with $p$ prime number. G is simple and abelian, $G=G\cdot G$ and $G \cap G=G\neq 1$.

Comment: A and B are proper in question